# Are reputation points really needed to edit Community Wiki posts?

Tags: bug, reputation, comments, edits, community-wiki

The text "community wiki" at the bottom of a post brings a (rollover) note saying that 100 rep is needed to edit such a post. The "add a comment" text (rollover) note says you need 5 rep to add a note.

I had 2 reputation points and could not add a comment to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555225/how-to-upgrade-julia-to-a-new-release/30564686#30564686) marked as an accepted answer. Then strangely enough, I could edit the actual community wiki post! Is this a bug, my misunderstanding, or are there other forces in action that I do not understand? :)

And seriously, how can I edit a post if I can not add a comment underneath it? :D

PS: Various Stack Exchange sites show different reputation points for my account. Is it possible that community wiki posts consider your reputation points from other Stack Exchange sites (not just the one you are currently on)? By the way, even if that is the case, I don't think my total reputation on all sites would add up to a 100...

Comment: It will be very difficult to change the current rules on privileges. Best advice is post good questions and answers. It's not that difficult to earn 100 rep points. For example, 10 upvotes for answers, 20 upvotes for questions, 50 successful edits. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't edit the post per se. You *suggested* an edit.

Anyone can suggest an edit to a post (even anonymous users), but without sufficient reputation that edit is put in to a queue to be peer reviewed before it is approved (or rejected).

You can see from the [suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13818172) that your suggested edit was approved by the original poster, who can always approve edits regardless of reputation. Your edit was actually rejected by one user, and your previous edit on the same post was rejected by two users, but the OP approved your edit in both cases.

You can read more about how suggested edits work here:

- **[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)**

Comment: Thanks Cai. I also just noticed that the editing history shows my edits with the sign "edit approved". So, like you said, I did not actually **edit** but merely **suggested edits** and my suggestions were approved very fast. However, I did not see the "peer review" warnings either; it seemed to me that my edits were instantenously placed. One way to test is making an edit and check it quickly but that would not be a proper behavior I guess... :) I also did not know that anyone could suggest an edit (although I had read the link you provided). Your explanation now makes sense.

Comment: You always see the edit applied instantly, but no one else will see it until it is approved (which I can see is a bit confusing!), you should see the message about it being peer reviewed too though, unless it really was approved that quick :)

Comment: A newbie question: If I notice that my question was not a good one in this case, do I delete it to avoid making noise and getting downvotes or do I leave it so that others who fall into the same trap can read and get informed?

Comment: In general it's up to you (unless it's off-topic then you probably should), but once you've got an answer that is upvoted and accepted I don't believe it will let you delete the question anyway.